# Nginx cache and nextjs manifest in responses produces 404 after release

Tags: nginx, next.js, caching, artifacts

we have nextjs and nginx. On nginx upstream has longest cache. We use docker to deploy, after release - we got many 404 in logs. Users browser got cached page response with path to specific chunks from old release.

What options to fix we have?

First - Don't use nginx cache.
Second - Use cdn for static files, but we doesn't have it.
Third - Keep old previus artifacts in new docker release?

Any ideas how to solve this problem?